# How do I make these media queries work?

Tags: css

I am trying to add media queries to my homepage banner image. I want it to be responsive and update to 3 different image sizes depending on the screen used. Currently only the medium sized image shows up. Please advise what is wrong with my code. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
/*---------------------------------------------
      Section#Slider [Banner Image]
-----------------------------------------------*/
/* NEXUS 5 Size 412px, XS
(less than 786px no media query since this is
default in Bootstrap)
*/

/* IPAD SIZE 768px and up, S*/

@media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    #slider {
        background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_640x285.jpeg") no-
        repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 10% 0%;
        padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
        position: relative;
    }
 }

/* MD, desktops, 992px and up */

@media (min-width: 950px) {
    #slider {
        background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_1280x570.jpeg") no-
        repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 10% 0%;
        padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
        position: relative;
    }
}

/* LG, large desktops, 1200px and up */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #slider {
        background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_1920x855.jpeg") no-
        repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 10% 0%;
        padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
        position: relative;
    }

}
```

Comment: try setting max-width too like "@media (min-width: 950px) and (max-width: 1199px){"

Comment: use  `max-width` instead of `min-width`

Comment: why instead of? he needs min-width too if i am not wrong @Eranda

Answer (score 2):

The main issue was you forgot to add screen in your 992px media query. I made the changes might be this is helpful.

```css
/*---------------------------------------------
      Section#Slider [Banner Image]
-----------------------------------------------*/
/* NEXUS 5 Size 412px, XS
(less than 786px no media query since this is
default in Bootstrap)
*/

/* IPAD SIZE 768px and up, S*/

@media screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:550px) {
    #slider {
        background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_640x285.jpeg") no-
        repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 10% 0%;
        padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
        position: relative;
    }
 }

/* MD, desktops, 992px and up */

@media screen and (min-width:551px) and (max-width:992px){
    #slider {
        background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_1280x570.jpeg") no-
        repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: 10% 0%;
        padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
        position: relative;
    }
}

/* LG, large desktops, 1200px and up */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle style of a spicifique screen size using [min and max media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 550px) and (max-width: 950px){
        #slider {
            background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_640x285.jpeg") no-
            repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: 10% 0%;
            padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
            position: relative;
        }
     }

    /* MD, desktops, 992px and up */

    @media (min-width: 950px)  and (max-width: 1200px){
        #slider {
            background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_1280x570.jpeg") no-
            repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: 10% 0%;
            padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
            position: relative;
        }
    }  
    @media (min-width: 1200px){
        #slider {
            background: url("../img/smartphoneweb_1920x855.jpeg") no-
            repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: 10% 0%;
            padding: 200px 0 280px 0;
            position: relative;
        }

    }
```